# Why do we normalise the spinor to $\frac{E}{m}$ and not just $E$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

The spinor, say $u(p)$, normalises to $\frac {E}{m}$. But the $m$ is at the bottom only because we defined $u(p)$ to have a $\sqrt {2m}$ in the denominator. So isn't this unnecessary? Just have a $\sqrt {2}$ at the bottom instead of $\sqrt {2m}$.

Also, later we cancel out this $m$ anyway. We define the general solution, composed of linear combinations of $v(p)$ and $u(p)$, to have a $\sqrt {m}$ in the numerator. This cancels out the previous $\sqrt {m}$ in the denominator.

So why are we introducing this $m$ for seemingly no reason?

Also, it makes even more sense to replace the $\sqrt {\frac{E+m}{2m}}$ factor in $u(p)$ with $\sqrt {\frac{E+m}{2E}}$. This way, $u(p)$ normalises to 1, and the form of the general solution becomes simpler:
$$\sum_{r} \sum_{p} \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} (a_r(p)u_r(p)e^{-ipx}+b^{\dagger}_r(p)v_r(p)e^{ipx})$$.

The earlier general solution had a $\sqrt{ \frac{m}{EV}}$ in the front.

Comment: Based on the letters you used, my guess is that you are referring to solutions of the Dirac equation, but you should add the necessary context (and a reference to whatever resource you happen to be following) to make this explicit.

Comment: @J.Murray Dirac equation is in the tag. The book is "Student Friendly Quantum Field theory" chapter 4